# GHC weird generated cost centre

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm having trouble understanding a heap profile. I compiled the program with `-fprof-auto` so cost centres would be automatically generated and a weird one appeared.

Program is structured as: main calls g, and g do all the work. (And main prints the output)

cost centres:

```
1. g/main/Main.CAF
2. g.\.\/g.\/g/main/Main.CAF
```

(g is recursive and keep composing functions which I believe will generate some thunks)

Another version which uses foldl has the following cost centres:

```
1. g/main/Main.CAF
2. g.\/g/main/Main.CAF
```

What are these others cost centres?

Thanks!!